# Exporting SVG as PNG without antialiasing

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, png

I have a similar issue to [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50613/create-vector-icons-and-export-them-later-as-png-without-antialiasing). I have this SVG in Inkscape:

[image: svg]

It's 22 x 22, and I've made sure to follow the advice in the linked answer and use a grid to align the contents.

When exporting to PNG, I export the entire page with an image width and height of 22. However, my image always comes out anti-aliased:

[image: anti-aliased]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the geometry of the export area is correct. For a 22x22 image, it should look like this:

[image: export]